# Webstorm 8 unable to run html

Tags: html, webstorm

I just rename to the index.html, and then my webstorm cannot run it in browser, however other file extension with .html can run, only name in index.html cannot, how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: image link as below since lower than 10 reputation:                                        https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/105496710207551484677/albums/6126660975174609713/6126660979542005874?pid=6126660979542005874&oid=105496710207551484677

Answer (score 1):

Please check if 'index.html' is added to text file patterns in `Settings | Editor | File types -> 'Text files'` file type. Removing this pattern should solve your problem